# Nginx downloading PHP files instead of serving them

Tags: nginx, download, php

I've recently set up an nginx server, I've been using ruby on it for the most part but when I followed a recent tutorial to get PHP working ([Tutorial located Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) and I didn't install MySQL) I cannot actually view PHP files without them downloading instead.

I've seen other scenarios like this on the internet but none of them seem to help my situation.

Here is my nginx config

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_name_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: check that the file `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` actually exists

Comment: /var/run/php5-fpm.sock does exist

Comment: try commenting the fastcgi split and fastcgi index lines and reload nginx, I usually don't use them.

Comment: do you have any other config files? try replacing the try files line in `location /` with `return 403;` for example, see if anything changes

Comment: I have 4 config files for 4 different domains

Comment: is this file symlinked to sites-enabled?

Comment: Yes, All files have symlinks.

Comment: Do you have any other config that has `default_server` too?

Comment: No, I do not have that file as well, should I?